# Seguridad en React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seguridad, frontend

queria preguntar por la seguridad del código en React.
¿Un usuario malintencionado podría inspeccionar y/o manipular variables, validaciones o rutas desde el navegador par acceder a recursos privados por ejemplo?
Vengo de PHP, estoy aprendiendo React y la verdad es que me da inseguridad que se hagan validaciones en el lado del cliente.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esto es como cualquier otro cliente, se pueden hacer cosas desde la terminal, lo que deberías hacer es que todas las validaciones ocurran en el servidor, el lenguaje de React tan solo es un lenguaje de para programar Frontend como cualquier otro

Comment: Las validaciones en frontend son para mejorar la experiencia de usuario: en lugar de esperar a las validaciones en backend, que sólo se hacen cuando se mandan los datos, el usuario puede saber si está haciendo algo no permitido casi en tiempo real.
Nunca asumas en el servidor que las validaciones en el cliente han funcionado, desactivarlas o ignorarlas es una tarea trivial para cualquier usuario con unos pocos conocimientos de JS o HTTP.

Comment: Si, de hecho con la extension de react para chrome puedes manipular el estado de la app, por eso es importante validar tanto en el front como en el back